# Booting from Grub instead of booting from Windows Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

Recently upgrade my laptop to Windows 10. Today I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3. After some problems with Grub I have been able to install Ubuntu. I created a partition for / boot.
When starting the computer starts Grub and options are; Ubuntu and Windows Boot Manager.
How I can make Windows boot from Grub instead of booting from Windows Boot Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so Windows will always boot from Windows Boot Manager. Why? Well, even if GRUB loads "Windows", it's just chainloading Windows Boot Manager, because it's the only thing that can actually load the Windows kernel (to my knowledge). You can, however, set GRUB as the default boot device in your laptop's BIOS/EFI and use GRUB to load Windows Boot Manager.